# Display UIActivityViewController in ActionSheet not Popover

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uiactivityviewcontroller

In iOS <7, the UIActivityViewController could be presented the same on iPads and iPhones, from the bottom of the screen, with a cancel button on the bottom.

With iOS 8, it appears that the UIActivityViewController desires to be presented inside a Popup on the iPad.

Is there any way to present the UIActivityViewController from the tab bar, so that it appears the same on iPads and iPhones? (like in the following picture)

[image: Activity View Controller iPhone]

Comment: check this out http://nshipster.com/uiactivityviewcontroller/